# Auto-Table generation in Cassandra with kafka connect cassandra sink

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am `using confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector`, for kafka connect cassandra sink.

I wanted to know if it was possible to auto-generate cassandra tables from the kafka topic using `io.confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector` as connector.

If it is possible, can you please suggest what configuration to set to enable this feature. I have tried all the configurations mentioned in the documentation, but I was not successful in creating a table.

This is the configuration i am using:

```
{
  "name": "cassandra-test4",

  "config": {

    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector",

    "tasks.max": "3",

    "topics": "orders-topic2",

    "cassandra.contact.points": "my_ip",

    "cassandra.keyspace": "test_cas",

    "cassandra.write.mode": "Insert",

    "cassandra.table.manage.enabled": "true",

    "cassandra.sink.route": "test_cas.orders",

    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",

    "flush.size": "1",

    "cassandra.keyspace.create.enabled": "true",

    "name": "cassandra-test4"

  },

  "tasks": [

    {

      "connector": "cassandra-test4",

      "task": 0

    },

    {

      "connector": "cassandra-test4",

      "task": 1

    },

    {

      "connector": "cassandra-test4",

      "task": 2

    }

  ],

  "type": null

}
```

Comment: Can you show your topic data, including the keys?

Answer (score 1):

This is should be done by setting `cassandra.keyspace.create.enabled` & `cassandra.table.manage.enabled` properties to `true`. See [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-cassandra/cassandra_sink_connector_config.html).

But be really careful - it's very easy to get schema disagreement in your cluster, and then you need to do additional steps to recover from it.  It's better pre-create tables before starting connector...

Comment: i have tried with the above properties, the keyspace is getting created but the table fails to get created.

Comment: How is your key looks like in Kafka?

Comment: I am producing test data from the cli producer with the following configuration:`kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic tt2  --property parse.key=true  --property key.schema='{"type":"string"}'  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'`

Comment: My data is : `"key1":{"f1": "value1"}`

Comment: You don’t see any errors in connectors log? It’s hard to say without logs... or source code for connector...

Comment: No, i don't see any errors in the logs, the logs show this: `INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group connect-test_cas with old generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-31) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)'`

Comment: `Stabilized group connect-test_cas generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-31) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-11-30 06:56:24,970] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Assignment received from leader for group connect-test_cas for generation 5 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-11-30 06:56:27,201] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group connect-test_cas with old generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-31) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)`

Comment: `[2018-11-30 06:56:27,202] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Group connect-test_cas with generation 6 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-31) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-11-30 06:56:47,508] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=3] Group connect-test_cas transitioned to Dead in generation 6 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)`

Comment: Maybe you can enable debug or trace logging?

Comment: @Yana Those don't look like logs of a Kafka Connect process, but rather logs for the group coordinator

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing out my error, I have check the connector logs and i am getting this error: `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Key must be a struct or
map. This connector requires that records from Kafka contain the keys for the Cass
andra table. Please use a transformation like org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.
ValueToKey to create a key with the proper fields.`

Comment: I have tried adding the transformer     `"transformers": "transforms.ValueToKey.type"`, but not resolving

Comment: @Yana `transformers` is not a valid Connect property. You need two json keys for defining a transform, `transforms : ValueToKey` and also `transforms.ValueToKey.type : org.apache.kafka.connect... `, and then another for saying which fields of the value create the key

Comment: Was able to load my data into cassandra, by using a struct key in data of kafka topic.